# Debian 11 LUKS mod: hang/freeze when init is supposed to start

Tags: boot-issues, debian, encryption, init

I'm trying to modify a Debian 11 Raspi image to boot from a LUKS device. When booting, the last lines being logged are HID (input device) detection, and after a couple of seconds:

```
kernel: random: crng init done
```

After that boot hangs. No prompt. No reaction to keypresses except Ctrl + Alt + Del (halt).

I followed the following answer's recipe to modify the Debian image to boot from a LUKS device:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1287837/luks-disk-encryption-on-raspberry-pi-4-and-ubuntu-desktop-20-10

What I made different:

- Pre modification

  - installed `cryptsetup-initramfs`
  - added `CRYPTSETUP=y` to `/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook` and `update-initramfs`
- From the recipe I deviated by

  - Storing the root partition to a .tar
  - Formatting a LUKS device on the root partition
  - Using another cipher (aes-xts-plain64)
  - Using LUKS type 1
  - Opening the LUKS device
  - Formatting EXT4 partition on the mapped device
  - Fixed the `cryptdevice` name after `:` to equal to the mapper name, not "sdcard"

## Question

Apparently `init` does not execute or crashes early. Adding `debug` to `cmdline.txt` does not show much more infos, except for this:

```
[5.12345] Run /init as init process
[5.12345]   with arguments:
[5.12345]     /init
[5.12345]   with environment:
[5.12345]     HOME=/
[5.12345]     TERM=linux
[5.12345]     cryptdevice=/dev/mmcblk1p2:rpirootfs
```

Are there any obvious errors? How can I further debug at what point / for what reason the start stop?

## My scripts

### Pre modification:

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade -y

cat <<-EOF >>/etc/initramfs-tools/modules
    algif_skcipher
    xchacha12
    adiantum
    aes_arm
    sha256
    nhpoly1305
    dm-crypt
EOF

echo “CRYPTSETUP=y” >> /etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook

apt-get install cryptsetup-initramfs

update-initramfs -c -u
```

### Encryption script

```
LUKS_CIPHER="aes-xts-plain64"
LUKS_NAME="rpirootfs"

# Inside Raspberry Pi
RPI_ROOT_DISK_NAME="/dev/mmcblk1p2"

MOUNT_RPI="/mnt"
PACKED_RPI="/media/ramdisk/rpi.tar"

luks_mapper_device="/dev/mapper/${LUKS_NAME}"

mount ${disk} ${MOUNT_RPI}

tar -C ${MOUNT_RPI} -Pcf ${PACKED_RPI} .

umount ${disk}

cryptsetup luksFormat -c ${LUKS_CIPHER} -s 256 -h sha512 --use-urandom ${disk}

cryptsetup luksOpen ${disk} ${LUKS_NAME}

mkfs.ext4 ${luks_mapper_device}

mount ${luks_mapper_device} ${MOUNT_RPI}

tar -C ${MOUNT_RPI} -xf ${PACKED_RPI}

echo "${LUKS_NAME} ${RPI_ROOT_DISK_NAME} none luks" > ${MOUNT_RPI}/etc/crypttab
echo "${luks_mapper_device} / ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0" > ${MOUNT_RPI}/etc/fstab

umount ${luks_mapper_device}

cryptsetup close ${LUKS_NAME}

mount ${boot_disk} ${MOUNT_RPI}

sed -i -r "s;root=LABEL=[^ ]+ ;root=${luks_mapper_device} ;" ${MOUNT_RPI}/cmdline.txt
sed -i -r 's/splash//' ${MOUNT_RPI}/cmdline.txt
sed -i -r "s;cryptdevice=[^ ]+;;" ${MOUNT_RPI}/cmdline.txt
sed -i -r "s;$; cryptdevice=${RPI_ROOT_DISK_NAME}:${LUKS_NAME};" ${MOUNT_RPI}/cmdline.txt

umount ${boot_disk}
```

Comment: Got it. I'll add an answer later, TL;DR is: the recipe uses an obsolete way of configuring cryptsetup for initramfs. Cryptsetup is configured by adding the `initramfs` option to `/etc/crypttab`. That means, that this has to be configured during the pre-modification stage by creating the file with `rpirootfs /dev/mmcblk1p2 none luks,initramfs`. Change the root partition in `/etc/fstab` to `/dev/mapper/rpirootfs / ext4 defaults,noatime 0 0`. Finally, the prompt was not visible because it was shown at the serial console. Ensure there's no `console=ttyS1,115200` in `console.txt`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## TL;DR

1. Configure cryptsetup via `initramfs` option in `/etc/crypttab`

   Setting the config variable in `/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook` is obsolete in Debian 11.

   The update-initramfs hooks will look for the option in the `crypttab` and trigger the appropriate initramfs preparation steps.
2. Configuring additional modules in `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules` is not required

   The initramfs-update hooks will automatically add all required modules.
3. Ensure the `console` option in `cmdline.txt` is `tty0`

   With only `console=tty0` the unlock prompt is sent to the monitor + keyboard terminal.

   The default configuration was `console=tty0 console=ttyS1,115200`, obviously sending the prompt to the serial console.

## Debugging process

When reading the `/etc/cryptsetup-initramfs/conf-hook` file, the configuration file contained a comment giving a hint on the proper configuration process:

> # Matching key files from the crypttab(5) are included in the initramfs image.

Manpages helped configuring the `crypttab` properly.

However, even with this fixed, the boot process gets stuck at

```
[   6.812345] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
[   6.812345] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.43.0-ioctl (2020-10-01) initialized: dm-devel@redhat.com
```

The good things is, that cryptsetup was obviously correctly configured because the device mapper module was added to initramfs.

Next troubleshooting steps involved

1. Adding `rootdelay=N` -  only delayed this message
2. Removing `rootwait` - does not change anything
3. Adding `debug` does not show more infos
4. Adding `break=premount` does not drop to a shell
5. Adding `break=top` does not drop to a shell but it also does no longer load the dm-crypt modules - as expected

This indicated that the init script is working properly. And now it dawned on me: is the console not the monitor + keyboard?

For sure!

I looked at the `cmdline.txt` and found:

```
console=tty0 console=ttyS1,115200
```

Man!

After removing `console=ttyS1,115200` initramfs now shows the shell with a `break` config.

So, afterall the unlock prompt was printed to the serial terminal.

References:

- https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/cryptsetup/crypttab.5.en.html
- https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/initramfs-tools-core/initramfs-tools.7.en.html

## Further tips

### Process optimizations

The process can and should be furhter optimized by not only creating the proper `fstab` and `crypttab` in the preparation step but also configuring the Rasperry Pi config update and kernel post-install scripts to regenerate `cmdline.txt` properly.

This outlines the process:

```
cat >/etc/default/raspi-extra-cmdline <<-EOF
    rootdelay=${INITRD_ROOTDELAY} cryptdevice=${RPI_ROOT_DISK_NAME}:${LUKS_NAME}
EOF

sed -i -r \
    -e "s;^#?(ROOTPART)=.*$;\1=${LUKS_MAPPER_DEVICE};" \
    -e "s/^#?(CONSOLES)=.*$/\1=${INITRD_CONSOLE}/" \
        /etc/default/raspi-firmware
```

The option `rootdelay` was added to give the kernel some time to end logging device detections to not printing into the password prompt.

### Debugging

The init script will dump much more detailed runtime information with the `debug` option in `cmdline.txt` set to a random string (i.e. `debug=foo`).